# Can't install snips-nlu-en in using pip3?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am trying to install snips-nlu-en but keep getting the following error:

```
sudo -H pip3 install snips-nlu-en

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 795, in get_page
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/models.py", line 935, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/snips-nlu-en/
```

Please advise how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such package: https://pypi.org/project/snips-nlu-en/ returns error 404. What are you trying to install?

There is [snips-nlu](https://pypi.org/project/snips-nlu/), is it what you want?

```
pip install snips-nlu
```

Comment: When I am trying to update all my Python packages I get the above error @phd

Comment: @SteveS Then you have to recollect where from you've installed it. Could be from PyPI but the package was later removed. There're many packages related to snips-nlu: https://pypi.org/search/?q=snips-nlu

Answer (score 1):

`snips-nlu-en` is a [resource package](https://snips-nlu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#language-resources) which is installed by `snips-nlu` when you run:

```
python -m snips_nlu download en
```

This resource package is [hosted on github](https://github.com/snipsco/snips-nlu-language-resources/releases) and not on pypi, which is why you can't install it directly through `pip install`.

The best way to get the up-to-date `snips-nlu-en` version is to first update `snips-nlu` with `pip install --upgrade snips-nlu` and then download the resources with the aforementioned command.